# Простейший чат на React.js + Socket.io

Tags: reactjs, socket.io, react-hook, socketio-client

Я пытаюсь создать простейщий чат "Тет-а-тет" на MERN + socket.io

Вот код сервера:

```js
io.on("connection", (socket) => {
    socket.join("room1");
    socket.on("CHAT:NEW_MESSAGE", (data) => {
        console.log("Серверный чат мессадж сработал!")
        socket.to("room1").emit("CHAT:NEW_MESSAGE", {
            chat_id: data.chat_id,
            type: data.type,
            message: data.message,
            user: {
                username: data.user.username,
                id: data.user.id
            }
          })
    });
})
```

А вот код из React:

```js
  useEffect(function() {
    socket.on("CHAT:NEW_MESSAGE", (data) => {
      setMsg(messages => [...messages, data])
    });
  }, [])

  const sendMessageHandler = () => {

    let newMessage = {
      chat_id: '0-1',
      type: "dm",
      message: currentMessage,
      user: {
          username: "Kirill",
          id: 0
      }
    }

    socket.emit("CHAT:NEW_MESSAGE", newMessage)

    setMsg(messages => [...messages, newMessage])
  }
```

Когда я отправляю сообщение на сервер, оно доходит исправить, в единственном экземпляре, но вот сервер почему то мне присылает не один экземпляр, а скажем 2! Как мне сделать так, что бы приходил только 1 экземпляр сообщения, и я мог его вставить в useState msg?

Comment: Понять, почему сервер присылает второй ответ. Вообще, судя по коду, второй экземпляр не будет отправлен, если не придет новый запрос от клиента. Как вариант, если это кусок кода, возможно что то  где то у вас по коду тригерит передачу данных клиенту

Comment: Вот у меня есть предположение, что при рендере страницы, useEffect происходит 2 раза, и в массив сообщений добавляется 2 сообщения, как этого можно избежать?

Comment: У вас в index.js режим `<StrictMode>` установлен? Обернут в данный компонент ваш основной App.js?

Comment: Нет, а для чего это?

Comment: В новых версиях реакт устанавливает компонент дважды в режиме StrictMode причем только в режиме разработки...

Comment: Обязательно попробую, скоро отпишу